# How do I delete all comments in .json file? (vscode)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, comments

I found the [Remove Comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycX5U.png) extension but this extension only supports html/css. Is there anyway to remove all comments on a json file?

Comment: an actual link to the extension page would be nice

Comment: here you go @rioV8 [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plibither8.remove-comments)

Comment: I have written a replacement of that extension: [Remove Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-remove-comments). It fixes a lot of the open issues of the other extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set the languageID of the file to: **JSON with comments** `jsonc`

it will remove the comments